# Git: How to structure repositories so I can rebase without getting "already up to date" messages

Tags: git, repository, rebase

Some years ago I worked on open source github projects - I cloned the project, and when I had something to commit I made a pull request. When I wanted to get the lates stuff from the main project I did a merge/rebase - at least that is how I remember it.

Now I have my own webserver on which I want to recreate the exact same workflow, but it doesn't seem to work - here is what I mean:

1. Dev A and B work on some changes.
2. Dev B commits his changes, creates a pull request.
3. maintainer accepts pull request.
4. Dev A continues working
5. Dev A finishes his changes, commits
6. **Dev A rebases to get B's changes from master**
7. Dev A creates a pull request.

Step 6 - rebasing - never works for me. I keep getting "already up to date" messages, and I don't see why.

I would appreciate a step-by-step guide on how to set up repositories, how to pull changes, and how to rebase. None of the online guides or other StackOverflow questions have been able to explain what I am doing wrong.

I am using the following git commands for the above setup, if you can spot a mistake please do tell:

1. I use `git init nighly` to create the repo - this becomes the integration repo
2. I copy my existing code into the integration rep, do `git add --all` and commit
3. I clone into repo dev-a and dev-b
4. when pulling changes, I go to the integration repo and do "`git pull dev-a master`"
5. afterwards I go into repo dev-b and do `git remote update` and `git rebase master` - but it says "Current branch master is up to date.".

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "but when trying to get these changes into the other developer repos using the rebase command it says "already up to date"." - rebase isn't how you push changes...

Comment: Then why did it work this way when I worked on github projects? Now I might remember wrongly, but I am pretty sure that that was how it worked.

Basically I want to recreate the github way of working, but without actually using github. If it works different than I remember, feel free to explain how you get changes from the master repo on github into your own developer repo.

Comment: No, you're remembering wrongly. Rebase is about incorporating *other* changes into your branch, applying your changes afterwards. It sounds like you're thinking of `git push` to push your changes up to another repo. Maybe you should revise how you got everything to work on github before trying in a less familiar environment.

Comment: @JonSkeet: But what you are describing is exactly what I want to do. Only it doesn't work.

Dev A works on changes.
Dev B commits his changes, creates a pull request.
maintainer accepts pull request.
Dev A continues working, and is finally ready to commit.
Now dev A should first get B's changes by rebasing from master before creating his own pull request- but this step doesn't work. Not ever. And I don't see why.

Comment: That's not what you described though - at least not clearly. You made it sounds like it's developer A trying to get their changes into developer B's repo by using rebase, which wouldn't work. It would help if you would post *exactly* what you're doing, what you expect to happen and what does happen.

Comment: I apologize if I was unclear, I hope it is much clearer now.

Comment: Just `git rebase` won't do it for you - you'd need `git rebase master` to say that you want to rebase from the master branch.

Comment: You are quite correct, that was another stupid omission. But the fact remaisn that when I rebase correctly it says "Current branch master is up to date."

Comment: At this point it's hard to know *exactly* what's happened - which commits you actually have in which branches and which remotes...

Comment: @JonSkeet many thanks for your time - would you look through my answer and see if I am doing anything wrong? I am especially concerned about having to specify the "origin" remote for the rebase command, it seems to me that that should be implied (hence the name origin), but it just will not work without. The rebase command also works without specifying the master branch, but I think I read somewhere that doing this is bad?

Comment: Well I'd always specify the branch, personally. I'd also use `git pull upstream master` rather than using `git remote update`, but I'm not a git expert, so can't really comment on whether or not what you're doing is "wrong".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I got it working.

I set up my repositories this way:

1. `git init integration` (integration repository)
2. `cp -r existing-source-dir/* integration/` (having removed the old .git directory in existing-source-dir so git does not get confused)
3. `cd integration`
4. `git add --all`
5. `git commit`
6. `cd..`
7. `git clone nightly dev-a`
8. `git clone nightly dev-b`

Whenever changes are ready in a development stream, I do the following:

1. `cd dev-a`
2. `git commit` (of course I am making sure that all relevant changes are added, and everything else is discarded first)
3. `git remote update && git rebase origin master`
4. `cd ../integration`
5. `git pull dev-a master`

This appears to work.

If I do not specify the "origin" remote when rebasing, the rebase will fail with "Current branch master is up to date".

Answer (score 1):

Consider updating your remotes before issuing the rebase command.  git reports 'already up to date' because it is not aware of the updated changes on the remote.  Use the following command:

```
git remote update
```

before trying to use `git rebase`

As an alternative, you can do `git pull --rebase` instead of `git rebase`, and that should handle the missing step of updating your remotes.

Comment: Thank you, this was a thing I actually forgot to do, but even after updating it says it's up to date.

Perhaps I will recreate my repos from scratch and try again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a local repository, you can `git pull` or `git rebase` against a remote in order to rebase / pull  / merge your remote's changes into your working tree.

You cannot use the `git rebase` command to push changes to a remote, however.  In order to push changes in your local repository into a remote repository, you must use the command `git push {remote}` or `git push {ssh / https url}`

If, however, you log into this other machine and are working in one of these other 'remote' repositories locally, you should be able to use the `git rebase` or `git pull` commands just as you had on the first machine.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help - it seems my original question was worded quite poorly. Would you be so kind as to look at my updated question and see if you can spot my mistake?